# Can vim check before running :make that current dir is parent of current file?

Tags: vim, makefile, build, editor, vim-plugin

If I'm editing two projects (a tool and one external lib for example) in the same vim session, I'll `:cd` as needed to the appropriate dir after changing source files and before running `:make`.

I'm looking for a way to check that vim is in the right directory before calling make. Can I change its behavior to check that the current dir is the parent of at least one file open in the current tab ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it all depends on how you set your environment. The way you describe your problem makes me think you don't have locally defined your `&makeprg` to match your current project (and that you don't **locally** change your current working directory to match the current buffer)

I often work on several projects simultaneously (*lib0*, *lib1* that depends on *lib0*, and *finalproduct* that depends on *lib1*). The key is that in the root directory of each project I have a [local vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) where I **locally** set `&makeprg` to compile the current project. If I jump to another window (currently) displaying a buffer belonging to another project, when I type `:make` I compile the project that current buffer belongs to.

IOW, my local `&makeprg` contains something like `'cd '.b:current_project_compilation_directory. ' && make $*'` -- indirectly this permits me to do out-of-sources compilation and to emulate different compilation modes (release, debug...)

Note that I've another plugin behind the scene that [automatically changes the current local directory to the root directory of the current project](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Project.md#312-auto-detect-the-project-root-path) (and not the directory of the current buffer).